# Brightness Controls doesn't work in HP G62 (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: laptop, brightness, hp

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I think everything is working except for the brightness controls of the laptop. Please answer.

Comment: what is graphics driver of your system? edit the question and post result of these two commands `lspci | grep VGA` and `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness`

Answer (score 1):

I have a same problem and this is the only solution I know...that is to assign different combo for the brightness,as `fn` key is undetected

1) Install [XDoTool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) and [Compiz](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

`sudo aptitude install xdotool compizconfig-settings-manager`

2) Open Compiz

Command : `ccsm`

3) Go to commands and add these lines:

`xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp`

`xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown`

In *commandLine1* and *commandLine2* respectively.

Now click on Key Bindings Tab and Click on disabled button

On the pop-up box click *Grab Key Combination* and choose desired keys (I use <kbd>Super(win)</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>, <kbd>Super(win)</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd>)

Don't forget to check *Enable Commands* on left hand panel

I hope it helps :-)

If you come across the keyboard layout for hp g62 please do post it...I too need it :-P